# basic_string<wchar_t> UTF16 encoding to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsstring, wchar-t

What is the best method to convert from a C++ `basic_string<wchar_t>` object with UTF16 encoding to an Objective-C NSString object?

Can I cast from wchar_t* to char* like so and still have stringWithCString use the string correctly?

```
[NSString stringWithCString:(char*)wideCharBasicString.c_str() encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

Thank you,
Shane

Comment: A `wchar_t` on iOS is 32-bit wide IIRC.

Comment: I just verified it is indeed 32-bit. How would I go about the same method with UTF32 encoding?

Comment: So NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S",wideCharBasicString.c_str()]; seems to do the trick. stringWIthCString was only giving me an empty NSString.

Also if anyone needs to use this like I did, the flag -fshort-wchar turns wchar_t to 16-bit on iOS.

Comment: To be very general, if you guarantee that your original string is UTF-16 (not just UCS-2), you could copy it into a `uint16_t[]`, then use `iconv` to create the desired encoding (if it differs from UTF-16) and then construct your NSString from there.

Answer (score 1):

If the buffer is UTF-16 encoded, you could do this:

```
    NSData* data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer
                                                 length:length
                                           freeWhenDone:NO] autorelease];
    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                             encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

`stringWithCString` looks like it barfs on multi-byte character buffers, stopping at the first NULL byte it finds.

[**UPDATE**]

I filed a bug with apple, and this is the expected behaviour, *apparently*. stringWithCString only supports 8-bit encodings and will stop at the first zero byte.

Comment: Okay it's old but I was in the same case : I confirm stringWithCString won't work with UTF16 in IOS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to do the converison:

```
NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S",wideCharBasicString.c_str()];
```

Also if anyone needs to use this like I did, the flag -fshort-wchar turns wchar_t to 16-bit on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

This is the least ugly way to do it (utf16):

```
NSString* nsstr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:str.c_str() length:str.length()];
```